# Broken disk doesn't let the system boot. DRDY

Tags: hard-drive, boot, gparted

The broken disk is a SSD, it is the only disk in this system.
Suddenly it started throwing an error at the POST, see image:[image]

I researched for solution but it looks like, that as I said, the disk is broken (or better, the controller might be).
Still, I wanted to try to at least recover my file.

1. I enabled the Hot Plug on the bios
2. Booted Gparted Live
3. Attached the disk and "Rescan the disks" on Gparted

I thought that perhaps this way I could get access to its content.
The result is that it loads forever and never show anything.

I don't have many other ideas on how I can "fix it" or backup those file I wanted to rescue.

In such situations is there anything one can do?

Comment: Usually we build a time machine to give a lecture to our past selves about taking and testing backups beforehand. Or experience this once and learn to do so from that point. It MIGHT be possible to disassemble the drive and use spare parts like the controller from another drive of the same model, but it's not even nearly as easy as having a backup system.

Comment: This is a test machine used for benchmarking hardware, i don't really mind about the disk because beside Windows there were really a few file I wanted to keep. My question heads more to "what to do when this happens?". Once it was just a matter of disabling some hdd's blocks. I do not know how to manually "fix" a ssd. I too thought about swapping controller (done already elsewhere) but I hoped in some other technical answer or software suggestion. thanks tho!

Comment: With SSD the disk itself can mark nonwritable, broken sectors causing the shrink of the drive when it ages. As it tries to write every sector evenly when possible, that's also an alarm to replace the drive ASAP. When the controller fails, it happens suddenly. By the means of recovery, HDDs are much easier, but the list is still short compared to all the other advantages SSD has.

Comment: You can always run a filesystem check on the disk (mounted from some live distro) to see if some partition data is recoverable (if gparted doesn't do that automatically).

Comment: Clear enough, thanks to both! I believe it is the controller the problem. The POST hangs just when it starts load the drives (see picture) and gparted is not able to rescan the disks because this broken one doesn't let the process continue, this said I believe other tools for checking the disk won't be able to do anything. I kept tried yesterday but no luck.. Thanks again!